# Finding a Regular Expression for the Given Language

Tags: regex, regular-language

I need to find a Regular Expression for L consists of all strings with at most two occurrences of the string 00 over the alphabet  `E = {0,1}.`

For example, `000` in L but `0000` not.

I tried to find it but I could not find it.Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Overlapping occurences count?  That's difficult, and might not be entirely possible, at least, not cleanly.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no extra information.

Comment: `1*(01+)*(00?(1+00|0)?)?(1+0)*1*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work (where `e` is the empty string):

```
(1|01)* (e|0|00|000|001(1|01)*00) (1|10)*
```

Whenever you have to solve a problem with regular expressions and have a condition saying "at most ...blah blah blah," you normally just have to list all the possibilities.

Comment: 00100 in this Language?

Comment: @g3d Yes, if you take all the `*` and have them repeat no times (i.e. they become the empty string), you can see 00100 as one of the options in the middle

Answer (score -1):

It's the inverse of `00.*00`

```
echo "000" | grep -v "00.*00"
```

Comment: `00100` is definitely in the described language, but you don't match it.